# How would I get the field 1 value as a integer varaible with gson?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, okhttp

I've been using thingspeak and I have been trying to parse the Json data and get field 1 to be read on a text view but I'm having trouble getting it as a varaible to use.

Here is some code to help you

```
private fun funButton1() {
        println("Attempting to get JSON data!")
        val url = "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1029606/feeds.json?results=1"

        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                println(body)

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val json = gson.fromJson(body, Json::class.java)
```

This is the kotlin code and here is the calsses I used for gson

```
class Json(val feeds: List<Feed>)
class Feed(val field1: Int)
```

And this is the json data

```
{
  "channel": {
    "id": 1029606,
    "name": "LED ",
    "description": "Acts as a medium for the phone and arduino \r\nRules : 1 = LED ON 0 = LED OFF ",
    "latitude": "0.0",
    "longitude": "0.0",
    "field1": "LED STATUS",
    "created_at": "2020-04-01T17:19:03Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-04-01T17:20:39Z",
    "last_entry_id": 25
  },
  "feeds": [
    {
      "created_at": "2020-05-11T02:58:07Z",
      "entry_id": 25,
      "field1": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now as you can see the field 1 data which is 1 is the thing I'm trying to get to use as a variable but I'm not sure how. The gson code does parse it or something (im not sure here is an image)
[gson debug showing the value being there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFl6K.png)
so does anyone know how I can get that value of that into the code so I can use it as a varaible I'm relly confused and don't know what to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`json.feeds[0].field1`